# How can I auto-populate a range from another tab based on a Data Validation selection in Google Sheets?

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets, auto-populate

I have been looking for info about this for sometime, but nothing seems to work.  I hope I'm going to explain this right, but here goes... I have a data validation setup (cell G31 on 'Fellowship Tracking' tab.) Based on whatever option is selected, I want it to pull data from a certain range on another tab in the same sheet ('ALL Stages+Pit'.) I put a link to the sheet at the bottom.

For an example, on the 'Fellowship Tracking' tab, cell G31, let's say I select the option Stage 1. Then starting in cell C33, I would like it to auto-populate the data from cells B3:G21 from the 'ALL Stages+Pit' tab. In addition, repeat the same for Stage 2 option pull from 'Fellowship Tracking', cells H3:M21 and Stage 3 option pull from 'Fellowship Tracking', cells N3-S21 and auto-populate starting in cell C33 like Stage 1 data. The 'Pit' option, I would like to pull data from the 'PIT Sheet' tab from cells A2-F17 and auto-populate starting in cell C33. So basically whatever option is chosen, it pulls the data from the ranges mentioned above and auto-populates the respective data starting in cell C33.

I hope I explained all that enough. I would to get info on how to do all that or is this not possible because of the way the data is setup?

Sheet Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KYSiVggIm7KIKxpJMnUhldrzsIaETCqyjOWJ1a9k1cI/edit?usp=sharing

Images:

['Fellowship Tracking' tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIhMO.jpg)

[image]

['ALL Stages+Pit' tab: Stages data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1sQm.jpg)

[image]

['ALL Stages+Pit' tab: Pit data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlCvB.jpg)

[image]

Comment: If you will provide me with images of the tabs involved I'd be glad to assist you.  Yes Images because I will not follow links to spreadsheets off of this site.

Comment: @Cooper - I added the image files. I hope those are what you were asking to see?

Comment: Do you have any other onEdit() functions either simple or installable?

Comment: @Cooper - I don't know what those are, so I'm going to say probably not.

Comment: Is okay if I show you how to move one and then you have to do the rest of them.  Is that okay?

Comment: @Cooper - Yea that's okay. That's what I planned on doing ^_^

Comment: So I'm going to build an onEdit() function that monitors G31 of 'Fellowship Track' and moves 'ALL Stages+Pit'B3:G21 to C33 of 'Fellowship Tracking' is that correct?

Comment: @Cooper - Yea, that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Here is the full clarified code for solving this issue. This solution is brought to you by @Cooper who set up the path to follow for completing the rest of the required features.

```js
function onMyEdit(e) {
  // gets the sheet changes have been made
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  // only look for changes on Fellowship Tracking as there is where we will be changing our "stages" cell
  if(sh.getName()!='Fellowship Tracking')return;
  
  // If Stage 1 is selected
  if(e.range.columnStart==7 && e.range.rowStart==31 && e.value=='Stage 1') {
  // get the right range from the right sheet for stage1 
    var srcrg=e.source.getSheetByName('ALL Stages+Pit').getRange('B3:G21');
  // get range where we want to populate the information
    var desrg=sh.getRange('C33');
 // populate the information
    srcrg.copyTo(desrg);
  }
  
    // If Stage 2 is selected
  if(e.range.columnStart==7 && e.range.rowStart==31 && e.value=='Stage 2') {
    var srcrg=e.source.getSheetByName('ALL Stages+Pit').getRange('H3:M21');
    var desrg=sh.getRange('C33');
    srcrg.copyTo(desrg);
  }  
  
   // If Stage 3 is selected
  if(e.range.columnStart==7 && e.range.rowStart==31 && e.value=='Stage 3') {
    var srcrg=e.source.getSheetByName('ALL Stages+Pit').getRange('N3:S21');
    var desrg=sh.getRange('C33');
    srcrg.copyTo(desrg);
  }  
  
   // If PIT is selected
  if(e.range.columnStart==7 && e.range.rowStart==31 && e.value=='PIT') {
    var srcrg=e.source.getSheetByName('PIT Sheet').getRange('A2:F17');
    var desrg=sh.getRange('C33');
    srcrg.copyTo(desrg);
  }    
  
}

// run this function to start the auto-complete programme
function createOnMyEditTrigger() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
// runs the function above as an onEdit function on the specfic spreadhseet
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onMyEdit').forSpreadsheet(ss.getId()).onEdit().create();
}
```

You can check the reference for further information in how to catch changes in sheets with onEdit() [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Answer (score 1):

**Copying a range from one sheet to another sheet within the same spreadsheet**

1. Install the script into the script editor.
2. You cannot run this script from the script editor because it requires the onEdit trigger event object.
3. I've added a script to make this an installable trigger.  If you run the function named 'creatOnMyEditTrigger()' just once to create only one trigger then the function should start responding whenever a user edits G31 and the value is equal to 'Stage 1';

The code:

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='Fellowship Tracking')return;
  if(e.range.columnStart==7 && e.range.rowStart==31 && e.value=='Stage 1') {
    var srcrg=e.source.getSheetByName('ALL Stages+Pit').getRange('B3:G2');
    var desrg=sh.getRange('C33');
    srcrg.copyTo(desrg);
  }
}

function createOnMyEditTrigger() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onMyEdit').forSpreadsheet(ss.getId()).onEdit().create();
}
```

Comment: 1. I found out the sheet does have an onEdit script for a date/timestamp when installing the one you gave. I don't know if that's why I cant get it to work. If not, then, 2. I installed the script above and input the function 'createOnMyEditTrigger(G31)' into a cell. The cell says it loads, but when I change cell G31, nothing happens.

Comment: None of the functions I have create can be used for cell functions.  In addition G31 is a validation cell isn't it?

Comment: Oh, my bad. I misunderstood when you said run the function then. Yea, G31 a validation cell. So when you say run the function, what did you mean by that?

Comment: Run it from the script editor.  Or if you wish you can go create the trigger manually

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. However, when the range populates upon being triggered, the formulas in those cells no longer work. Any recommendation on how to get them to still work?

Comment: You didn't say anything about formulas in those cells

Comment: Can you explain further?

Comment: Sorry, didn't think about that. Still learning Sheets. The formula is 'hlookup($F$3,'Stage 1'!$E$34:$H$50,2,false)'. I changed the formula to 'hlookup('ALL Stages+Pit'!$F$3,'Stage 1'!$E$34:$H$50,2,false) then it came back. So my guess is to change each formula to include the tab name?

Comment: Yes @pixxidust that is right, you need to specify the sheet name in all your formulas to solve the issue.